# DOM element id , is changed after rendering

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I use kendo view , 
my html code is :

```
<div id="permission" data-role="tabstrip" data-animation="false">
    <ul class="bd-doc-navigation-tabstrip tabstip-header" data-freezable="false">
        <li class="k-state-active">
            <p>Rigs</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Actors</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="permission-tabstrip-1"></div>
</div>
```

but after rendering page instead of "permission-tabstrip-1" I see "permission-1".
I dont know whats going happen . I havent used  "permission-tabstrip-1" anywhere else .

Answer (score 0):

I changed :

```
<div id="permission" data-role="tabstrip" data-animation="false">
```

to :

```
<div id="permission-tabstrip" data-role="tabstrip" data-animation="false">
```